# What does this statement means in C11 standard (about variadic functions)?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, variadic-functions, c11

At $6.5.2.2.6 the C11 standard:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on
>   each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to
>   double. These are called the default argument promotions. If the
>   number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
>   behavior is undefined. **If the function is defined with a type that
>   includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis
>   (, ...) or the types of the arguments after promotion are not
>   compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is
>   undefined.** If the function is defined with a type that does not
>   include a prototype, and the types of the arguments after promotion
>   are not compatible with those of the parameters after promotion, the
>   behavior is undefined, except for the following cases: ...

What does that means - I really can't understand it (especially the first part). From what I can however it means that defining a function like this:

```
void func(int a, int b, ...)
{
}
```

And then calling it is undefined behavior which I think is silly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The situation is as follows: You can declare a function without a parameter list and call this function:

```
int main(void)
{ 
    extern void f();   // no parameter list!
    char c = 'x';
    f(c, 1UL, 3.5f);
}
```

In this situation, the arguments are default-promoted: The first argument is promoted to either `int` or `unsigned int` (depending on the platform), the second remains `unsigned long`, and the third is promoted to `double`.

When the program is linked, some translation unit needs to contain the definition of the function. The definition always contains a parameter list, even if it's empty (but an empty parameter list in the definition means that the function takes no parameters, unlike in the declaration-that-is-not-a-definition above, where it just means that no information is provided about the parameters):

```
void f(int, unsigned long, double)
{
    // ...
}
```

The standardese you quoted now says that the behaviour is undefined if the parameter types in this definition are not compatible with the promoted types of the call, or if the parameter list ends with an ellipsis.

As a corollary, it follows that if you want to use a function with variable arguments (using the facilities of `<stdarg.h>` to access the arguments), you must declare the function with a prototype:

```
extern void f(int, ...);   // prototype (containing ellipsis)
f(c, 1UL, 3.5f);
```

Now `c` is converted to `int` because the first parameter is typed, and the second and third arguments are default-promoted just as before because they are passed as part of the ellipsis. The definition of `f` must now use the same declaration. If you will, passing arguments in a way that the `<stdarg.h>` facilities can access may require advance knowledge from the compiler, so you have to provide the parameter list before making the call.

Answer (score 2):

The wording is a bit confusing.  The whole paragraph is talking about the case where no prototype has been declared for the function at the time it is called, so the section you highlighted is for the case where no prototype is declared when the function is called, but a prototype is used when the function is defined.  Here is an example:

```
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    f(3.0f); /* undefined behavior */
    g(3.0);  /* undefined behavior */
}

int f(float v)
{
    return v;
}

int g(double v,...)
{
    return v;
}
```

In this example, when `f` is called, no prototype has been declared, so `3.0f` is promoted to a `double`.  However, the function is later defined with a prototype which takes a `float` instead of a `double`, so the behavior is undefined.

Likewise for `g`, the behavior is undefined because the elipses are used in the prototype of the definition.

Comment: This C standard is weird. Where are the ellipsis involved in all of this you're showing me? Because they exists in the standard statement I highlighted.

Comment: @FISOCPP The sentence you highlighted mentions two cases, one of them involving `...` parameters. Vaughn Cato's example refers to the other case.

Comment: @FISOCPP: The section you highlighted was for two different cases.  I've extended my answer to include the elipses case as well.

Comment: Which also means that we can instance functions without defining or declaring them before?

Comment: @FISOCPP: That is true, but it is a separate issue.  When you call a function that has not been declared, it is implicitly declared as a function returning int with no prototype.  Alternatively, you could have the function declared, but not have a prototype (empty parentheses)`.